# Joining the rows of one table to the columns of another in SQL

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join

I have the following two tables in SQLite:

transactions:

| ID | Department |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | IT |
| 2 | Customer Service |
| 3 | Cleaning |

standards:

| IT | Customer Service | Cleaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9.12 | 17.8 | 24.86 |

I want to join these two tables so the numbers in the second table become rows in my first table based on the matching value in the second table. The resulting table would look like this:

| ID | Department | Standard |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | IT | 9.12 |
| 2 | Customer Service | 17.8 |
| 3 | Cleaning | 24.86 |

How can I join these, as I'm using the rows of one table and the columns of another?

Comment: MySQL and SQLite are two totally different DBMSs, with different functionality and syntax. It is highly unlikely that you are using both simultaneously. Please [edit] your post to remove the tag that does not apply. Tag spamming is highly discouraged here, and is a very quick way to have your post downvoted and/or closed. Tags have meaning and relevance here, and should be used properly. In addition, mis-tagging your question delays your getting help and risks wasting the time of people who write an answer only to find out it won't work in the DBMS you're actually using.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `CROSS` join of the tables and a `CASE` expression to pick the appropriate standard:

```
SELECT t.*,
       CASE t.Department
         WHEN 'IT' THEN s.IT
         WHEN 'Customer Service' THEN s.`Customer Service`
         WHEN 'Cleaning' THEN s.Cleaning
       END AS Standard
FROM transactions t JOIN standards s;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oDPKGUuGANVbFH4KRVUoGU/0).